# Sitemap for https Ecommerce Site

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

I have few queries related to XML sitemap for better SEO. I'm having an ecommerce site with more than 30000 products. The site can be accessed via https as well as http.

1. While submitting xml sitemap to google, which is preferable? xml sitemap with https link or sitemap with http links. Which would be efficient?
2. Also can I have sitemap for both https and http links?
3. Since I have large database of products, I had to break sitemaps separately for products (5000 links in each sitemap), category sitemap and a common pages sitemap and finally an index sitemap containing all other sitemap links. Is it acceptable?
4. How to tell google to delete old links that was crawled during previous sitemap submission ,and index the latest links in sitemap?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Ad question 4:**

> If you have a web page that you just deleted but it is still showing
>   up in your custom search results, and it is very important to you that
>   it does not show up in search results as soon as possible; or if one
>   of your web pages contains inappropriate content and you want to block
>   it immediately while taking it down, you can prefix the URL with a "-"
>   symbol, and submit it in the On-demand indexing using individual URLs
>   section, like this:
>
> -http://www.example.com/outdated.html
>
> Source: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing

Have you tried Google Webmasters Tools? That and it's docs might help you.

Comment: I am blind in the morning. In such case I'm not sure whether G. allows to do that other way than just redirecting old pages to something meaningful, which helps you to promote your site.

Google Webmasters have a removal tool, but...
_Don’t use the URL tool to get rid of pages in these circumstances:

    To clean up cruft, like old pages that 404. If you recently changed your site and now have some outdated URLs in the index, Google's crawlers will see this as we recrawl your URLs, and those pages will naturally drop out of our search results. There's no need to request an urgent removal._